# Python не видит колонку в массиве

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

***Имеется такой код:***

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import string


stoplist = ['able', 'about', 'above', 'abroad', 'according', 'accordingly', 'across', 'actually', 'adj', 'after', 'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'ago', 'ahead', "ain't", 'all', 'allow', 'allows', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', 'alongside', 'already', 'also', 'although', 'always', 'am', 'amid', 'amidst', 'among', 'amongst', 'an', 'and', 'another', 'any', 'anybody', 'anyhow', 'anyone', 'anything', 'anyway', 'anyways', 'anywhere', 'apart', 'appear', 'appreciate', 'appropriate', 'are', "aren't", 'around', 'as', "a's", 'aside', 'ask', 'asking', 'associated', 'at', 'available', 'away', 'awfully', 'back', 'backward', 'backwards', 'be', 'became', 'because', 'become', 'becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'begin', 'behind', 'being', 'believe', 'below', 'beside', 'besides', 'best', 'better', 'between', 'beyond', 'both', 'brief', 'but', 'by', 'came', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', "can't", 'caption', 'cause', 'causes', 'certain', 'certainly', 'changes', 'clearly', "c'mon", 'co', 'co.', 'com', 'come', 'comes', 'concerning', 'consequently', 'consider', 'considering', 'contain', 'containing', 'contains', 'corresponding', 'could', "couldn't", 'course', "c's", 'currently', 'dare', "daren't", 'definitely', 'described', 'despite', 'did', "didn't", 'different', 'directly', 'do', 'does', "doesn't", 'doing', 'done', "don't", 'down', 'downwards', 'during', 'each', 'edu', 'eg', 'eight', 'eighty', 'either', 'else', 'elsewhere', 'end', 'ending', 'enough', 'entirely', 'especially', 'et', 'etc', 'even', 'ever', 'evermore', 'every', 'everybody', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'ex', 'exactly', 'example', 'except', 'fairly', 'far', 'farther', 'few', 'fewer', 'fifth', 'first', 'five', 'followed', 'following', 'follows', 'for', 'forever', 'former', 'formerly', 'forth', 'forward', 'found', 'four', 'from', 'further', 'furthermore', 'get', 'gets', 'getting', 'given', 'gives', 'go', 'goes', 'going', 'gone', 'got', 'gotten', 'greetings', 'had', "hadn't", 'half', 'happens', 'hardly', 'has', "hasn't", 'have', "haven't", 'having', 'he', "he'd", "he'll", 'hello', 'help', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', "here's", 'hereupon', 'hers', 'herself', "he's", 'hi', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'hither', 'hopefully', 'how', 'howbeit', 'however', 'hundred', "i'd", 'ie', 'if', 'ignored', "i'll", "i'm", 'immediate', 'in', 'inasmuch', 'inc', 'inc.', 'indeed', 'indicate', 'indicated', 'indicates', 'inner', 'inside', 'insofar', 'instead', 'into', 'inward', 'is', "isn't", 'it', "it'd", "it'll", 'its', "it's", 'itself', "i've", 'just', 'k', 'keep', 'keeps', 'kept', 'know', 'known', 'knows', 'last', 'lately', 'later', 'latter', 'latterly', 'least', 'less', 'lest', 'let', "let's", 'like', 'liked', 'likely', 'likewise', 'little', 'look', 'looking', 'looks', 'low', 'lower', 'ltd', 'made', 'mainly', 'make', 'makes', 'many', 'may', 'maybe', "mayn't", 'me', 'mean', 'meantime', 'meanwhile', 'merely', 'might', "mightn't", 'mine', 'minus', 'miss', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'mr', 'mrs', 'much', 'must', "mustn't", 'my', 'myself', 'name', 'namely', 'nd', 'near', 'nearly', 'necessary', 'need', "needn't", 'needs', 'neither', 'never', 'neverf', 'neverless', 'nevertheless', 'new', 'next', 'nine', 'ninety', 'no', 'nobody', 'non', 'none', 'nonetheless', 'noone', 'no-one', 'nor', 'normally', 'not', 'nothing', 'notwithstanding', 'novel', 'now', 'nowhere', 'obviously', 'of', 'off', 'often', 'oh', 'ok', 'okay', 'old', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'ones', "one's", 'only', 'onto', 'opposite', 'or', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise', 'ought', "oughtn't", 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'outside', 'over', 'overall', 'own', 'particular', 'particularly', 'past', 'per', 'perhaps', 'placed', 'please', 'plus', 'possible', 'presumably', 'probably', 'provided', 'provides', 'que', 'quite', 'qv', 'rather', 'rd', 're', 'really', 'reasonably', 'recent', 'recently', 'regarding', 'regardless', 'regards', 'relatively', 'respectively', 'right', 'round', 'said', 'same', 'saw', 'say', 'saying', 'says', 'second', 'secondly', 'see', 'seeing', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'seen', 'self', 'selves', 'sensible', 'sent', 'serious', 'seriously', 'seven', 'several', 'shall', "shan't", 'she', "she'd", "she'll", "she's", 'should', "shouldn't", 'since', 'six', 'so', 'some', 'somebody', 'someday', 'somehow', 'someone', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhat', 'somewhere', 'soon', 'sorry', 'specified', 'specify', 'specifying', 'still', 'sub', 'such', 'sup', 'sure', 'take', 'taken', 'taking', 'tell', 'tends', 'th', 'than', 'thank', 'thanks', 'thanx', 'that', "that'll", 'thats', "that's", "that've", 'the', 'their', 'theirs', 'them', 'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', "there'd", 'therefore', 'therein', "there'll", "there're", 'theres', "there's", 'thereupon', "there've", 'these', 'they', "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", 'thing', 'things', 'think', 'third', 'thirty', 'this', 'thorough', 'thoroughly', 'those', 'though', 'three', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'till', 'to', 'together', 'too', 'took', 'toward', 'towards', 'tried', 'tries', 'truly', 'try', 'trying', "t's", 'twice', 'two', 'un', 'under', 'underneath', 'undoing', 'unfortunately', 'unless', 'unlike', 'unlikely', 'until', 'unto', 'up', 'upon', 'upwards', 'us', 'use', 'used', 'useful', 'uses', 'using', 'usually', 'v', 'value', 'various', 'versus', 'very', 'via', 'viz', 'vs', 'want', 'wants', 'was', "wasn't", 'way', 'we', "we'd", 'welcome', 'well', "we'll", 'went', 'were', "we're", "weren't", "we've", 'what', 'whatever', "what'll", "what's", "what've", 'when', 'whence', 'whenever', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein', "where's", 'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'whichever', 'while', 'whilst', 'whither', 'who', "who'd", 'whoever', 'whole', "who'll", 'whom', 'whomever', "who's", 'whose', 'why', 'will', 'willing', 'wish', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'wonder', "won't", 'would', "wouldn't", 'yes', 'yet', 'you', "you'd", "you'll", 'your', "you're", 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', "you've", 'zero', 'a', "how's", 'i', "when's", "why's", 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'uucp', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'I', 'www', 'amount', 'bill', 'bottom', 'call', 'computer', 'con', 'couldnt', 'cry', 'de', 'describe', 'detail', 'due', 'eleven', 'empty', 'fifteen', 'fifty', 'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'forty', 'front', 'full', 'give', 'hasnt', 'herse', 'himse', 'interest', 'itse”', 'mill', 'move', 'myse”', 'part', 'put', 'show', 'side', 'sincere', 'sixty', 'system', 'ten', 'thick', 'thin', 'top', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'abst', 'accordance', 'act', 'added', 'adopted', 'affected', 'affecting', 'affects', 'ah', 'announce', 'anymore', 'apparently', 'approximately', 'aren', 'arent', 'arise', 'auth', 'beginning', 'beginnings', 'begins', 'biol', 'briefly', 'ca', 'date', 'ed', 'effect', 'et-al', 'ff', 'fix', 'gave', 'giving', 'heres', 'hes', 'hid', 'home', 'id', 'im', 'immediately', 'importance', 'important', 'index', 'information', 'invention', 'itd', 'keys', 'kg', 'km', 'largely', 'lets', 'line', "'ll", 'means', 'mg', 'million', 'ml', 'mug', 'na', 'nay', 'necessarily', 'nos', 'noted', 'obtain', 'obtained', 'omitted', 'ord', 'owing', 'page', 'pages', 'poorly', 'possibly', 'potentially', 'pp', 'predominantly', 'present', 'previously', 'primarily', 'promptly', 'proud', 'quickly', 'ran', 'readily', 'ref', 'refs', 'related', 'research', 'resulted', 'resulting', 'results', 'run', 'sec', 'section', 'shed', 'shes', 'showed', 'shown', 'showns', 'shows', 'significant', 'significantly', 'similar', 'similarly', 'slightly', 'somethan', 'specifically', 'state', 'states', 'stop', 'strongly', 'substantially', 'successfully', 'sufficiently', 'suggest', 'thered', 'thereof', 'therere', 'thereto', 'theyd', 'theyre', 'thou', 'thoughh', 'thousand', 'throug', 'til', 'tip', 'ts', 'ups', 'usefully', 'usefulness', "'ve", 'vol', 'vols', 'wed', 'whats', 'wheres', 'whim', 'whod', 'whos', 'widely', 'words', 'world', 'youd', 'youre']
text1 = str(input("Paste text here: "))
words1 = [s.lower() for s in text1.split() if s.lower() not in stoplist]
words1 = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in words1]


data = {'words': words1}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df['words'].value_counts()
df['total'] = df.sum()
df['percentage'] = (df['total'] / df['words']).round(2)

print('This text contains', total, 'words total')
display(df)
```

***Ожидаемый вывод:***

```
What is Lorem Ipsum?  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown  printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a  type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,  but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  remaining essentially unchanged.   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset  sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently  with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker  including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
This text contains 50 words total

lorem           5    50   0.1
ipsum           5    50   0.1
dummy           2    50   0.025
text            2    50   0.025
...            ...   ...   .....
```

Однако выбивает следующую ошибку:

```
KeyError: 'words'
```

Как переписать код, чтобы такого не было?

Comment: df = df['words'].value_counts()  - ничего не смущает? вы переписали переменную df, и теперь там нет датафрейма

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут сразу несколько ошибок. Строки, которые я исправил:

```py
df = df['words'].value_counts().to_frame()
total = df.sum().sum()
df['percentage'] = (100 * df['words'] / total).round(2)
```

- `value_counts()` возвращает `Series`, а вы явно хотите дальше обращаться как с датафреймом, как вариант можно превратить результат в датафрейм с помощью `.to_frame()`
- `df.sum()` опять же даёт `Series`, а вам нужен скаляр, для этого нужно ещё раз сделать `sum()`
- `total` не имеет смысла помещать в колонку - это единственное число, для него достаточно числовой переменной
- проценты считаются не так, как вы это сделали